# How to deal with application/octet-stream (uncompressed gzipped file) in PHP?

Tags: php, gzip, guzzle

I've to parse a lot (10000+) of remote gzipped files. Each zipped file should contain a CSV inside it (maybe in a folder). Right now I'm able to get the body, check for content type and uncompress it, obtaining `application/octet-stream`.

Question is: what's the octet-stream and how can I check for files or folders inside it?

```php
    /** @var $guzzle \Guzzle\Http\Client */
    $guzzle  = $this->getContainer()->get('guzzle');
    $request = $guzzle->get($url);

    try {
        $body = $request->send()->getBody();

        // Check for body content-type
        if('application/z-gzip' === $body->getContentType()) {
            $body->uncompress(); 
            $body->getContentType(); // application/octet-stream
        }
        else {
            // Log and skip current remote file
        }
    }
    catch(\Exception $e) {
        $output->writeln("Failed: {$guzzle->getBaseUrl()}");
        throw $e;
    }
```

Comment: Did any of the answers below assist this old question, @gremo?

Answer (score 1):

The EntityBody object that stores the body can only guess the content-type of local files. Use the content-length header of the response to get a more accurate value.

Something like this:

```
$response = $request->send();
$type = $response->getContentType();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like some shell command will work for u

```
shell_exec('gzip -d your_file.gz');
```

You can first unzip all your files in a particular directory and then can read each file or whatever computation you have to perform.

As a sidenote :

Take care where the command is run from (ot use a swith to tell "decompress to that directory")
You might want to take a look at escapeshellarg too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the built in gzuncompress function.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzuncompress.php

Edit: Or other zlib functions depending on what data you are working with. http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zlib.php